# My backup has a directory with the name ",." How to remove it?

Tags: filesystem

I have no idea where this file, or direcrtory, came from. I assume a typo for "..". `ls -ls` results in `??????` instead of `rwx-----` and `rm` reports too many links.

I have reformatted the disk and reinstalled, but would like to know how to get rid of such things for future reference.

Note: I have reformatted the drive therefore further testing is not possible.

Comment: Did you try quoting the filename, or escaping the characters in the `rm` command?

Comment: yes I tried all the usual methods of removing it e.g. rm -rf  on the parent directory and var5ious combinations of ",." \ * and ? but all returned the same result "too many links"  ls and find also failed, I don't remember their errors

Comment: I don't know what that actually means, but is this a server or a desktop?  If it's a desktop, what I would do is open it `nautilus` and then just go to that directory and delete it using its graphical interface.  I'm not sure if you tried that?

Comment: This is an experimental installation without a desktop, but multiple users with samba access, it is  used as a sort of server. to save space/. No I didn't try nautilus.